# For proper CakePHP conventions, how would I go about storing pieces of a script file that I would put together in execution?

Tags: cakephp, text, cakephp-2.1

I'm working on a little project in which CakePHP will be outputting script which will be interpreted by another client.

Thus far I have a layout setup which properly displays the script and only the script.  I simply set it into an array, which each new line as a new row in the array.  The view then just rolls through a foreach to display them, no problem.  This is working perfectly.

Now what I would like to do is have cake slice and dice different pre-made script portions together.  Basically I would store 'methods' as individual files of some kind, which can then be called by cakephp as needed and put together to make a single script.

What I'm wondering is:
a.  If I'm following the cake conventions, where and how should these text files be stored?
b.  What's the easiest way to call these files and set them into an array?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a.
I woud create a folder named `Scripts/` in the `app/View/Elements/` folder.
For each individual script, create a file in that folder. E.g. `somefunction.ctp`.
Those scripts can than be printed by calling `echo $this->element('Scripts/somefunction');` (omit the '.ctp' extention)

b.
Putting the content of these files in an array could go like this:

```
array_push( code_array, $this->element('Scripts/somefunction') );
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your feedback!  I suspect that will be my route!

Comment: No problem! Enjoy Cake. If you like, you can mark the answer as correct (extra karma for me :)

Comment: Ha ha, I always give it a day to let others answer before I mark, just because they tend to avoid the question if it's already got an accepted answer, and I find multiple opinions beneficial.  :)

Comment: You may be able to answer the related question I just posted as well if you're interested in more rep, as I am in answers, lol.